# interval between systimestamp problem (oracle)

Tags: oracle, intervals, systimestamp

I have a procedure TTT.

```
v_start_date     TIMESTAMP;
v_delta_interval interval day to second;
begin
 v_start_date := SYSTIMESTAMP;
 /* some code */
 v_delta_interval := SYSTIMESTAMP - v_start_date;
 insert into tmp_log_table
  values (v_start_date, v_delta_interval, SYSTIMESTAMP);
end;
```

The problem is with interval between systimestamp (***v_delta_interval***).
If a job runs the procedure - it's all ok, but if a user runs it - sometimes it calculated as +4 hours.
My log table:

```
create table tmp_log_table
(
  t_v_start_date     TIMESTAMP(6),
  t_v_delta_interval INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6),
  t_timestamp_log    TIMESTAMP(6)
);
```

and sometimes I have such values in tmp_log_table:

```
SQL> select cast(t_timestamp_log - t_v_start_date as INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)) as CLC_INTERVAL,
            T_V_DELTA_INTERVAL,
            t_timestamp_log,
            T_V_START_DATE
       from tmp_log_table t;

CLC_INTERVAL                            T_V_DELTA_INTERVAL                      T_TIMESTAMP_LOG                                   T_V_START_DATE
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------
+00 00:00:31.897890                     +00 04:00:31.895883                     20-JAN-20 11.30.28.825271 AM                      20-JAN-20 11.29.56.927381 AM
+00 00:00:46.392905                     +00 04:00:46.382724                     21-JAN-20 09.14.28.866425 AM                      21-JAN-20 09.13.42.473520 AM
```

Why do I have +4 hours difference between values in procedure?

Comment: I think the problem is that SYSTIMESTAMP has timezone, but the variable ***v_start_date*** does not have it.

Comment: Does the user uses `LOCALTIMESTAMP` instead of `SYSTIMESTAMP`?

Comment: I don't think SYSTIMESTAMP is the problem, because when cast to `TIMESTAMP` then Oracle simply drops the time zone. It should be always the same, provided `SYSTIMESTAMP` is used everywhere.

Comment: `SYSTIMESTAMP` is returned in time zone of database server's operating system. Typically this does not change, I strongly assume you are not using `SYSTIMESTAMP` everywhere.

Comment: so, at first, I changed my ***tmp_log_table***:
type `TIMESTAMP(6)` to `TIMESTAMP(6) with time zone.`
so, the values of **t_v_start_date** becomes +7:00 and the values of **t_timestamp_log** becomes +3:00.
then, the next step was to change declaration of variable **v_start_date** from `TIMESTAMP` to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and that solved the problem (in table both columns **t_v_start_date** and **t_timestamp_log** becomes +3:00)